# Can't create simple Android widget in Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-widget

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 12.1 to create a simple desktop widget.

I created a very minimal project from network guidies. It builds, but when I put the widget on home screen it says "Loading" and following errors appear in log:

```
08-02 20:44:37.844: WARN/ResourceType(12463): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
08-02 20:44:37.844: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(12463): Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.example.kbs/com.example.KbsProvider}): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

I tried with two phones (HTC Incredible S, Sony Xperia SP)

My Android manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.kbs">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".KbsProvider" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                       android:resource="@xml/kbs_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My `xml/kbs_widget_provider.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="18000000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main">
</appwidget-provider>
```

And I even tried with minimal`layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java class is:

```
package com.example.kbs;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class KbsProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
}
```

I'm not sure, what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `xml/kbs_widget_provider.xml` file.
I forgot `schema` for `xmlns:android` attribute.

The correct one is:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`